# White page instead of facebook log-in result

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I want to implement login with facebook in my website, but there are some problems. The problem is that after redirecting from facebook to my website I see a code in the url but no session. Because when $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); is called program is crashed (and it does not continue the code). The result is a white page after redirecting. [This is my webpage url](http://1stquest.com/test/index.php) 

Here is my code :

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$app_id = 'MY_ID';
$app_secret = 'MY_SECRET';
$app_url = 'http://1stquest.com/test/index.php';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($app_url);
try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (isset($session)){
    echo 'Success';
}
else{
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log In</a>';
}

?>
```

Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't correctly setup the app on developers.facebook.com
You have to finish the setup ther first.

Comment: It seems to be complete. In My App page>Settings>Basic I filled all of fields except Namespace and Mobile Site Url.

Comment: Did you set `$app_id = 'MY_ID'` only for this post or is it the same in your code? Same for `$app_secret = 'MY_SECRET'`. You have to insert your data here.

Comment: It is only for this post, and it is correct in real code.